# Regex Replace markup code C#

Tags: c#, regex

Okay, so I'm still pretty inexperienced in regex, so I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

On a website, we have a simple markup language for placing specific fields and values in a template.

It can look like any of these:

```
[%FieldName]
[%FieldName.Value]
[%FieldName.Text]
[%FieldName.Value_YesNo]
```

I can replace those no problem. But if a particular field doesn't have a value it ends up breaking images, links show up that don't actually go anywhere, etc. I tried accomplishing it with something like this:

```
[? <a href="[%FieldName.Value]">[%FieldName.Value]</a> ?]
```

And, using a `Regex.Replace()` I should be able to remove that whole line. However, it ended removing all of them.

```
    [? <a href="[%FieldName.Value]">[%FieldName.Value]</a> ?] [? <a href="[%Field2Name.Value]">[%Field2Name.Value]</a> ?]
```

`[[\[\?.*\[%FieldName.*\].*\?\]]+]` is something similar to what I have tried.

Also I've tried surrounding `FieldName` with parentheses, quotes, anything in an attempt to match the whole word rather than just the letters inside of it.

Any ideas?

I should also note I've tried the `\b` flag in various ways, too.

I already have this code that handles filling in the field information:

```
listingTemplate = listingTemplate.Replace("[%" + df.FieldName + "]", df.FieldText + ": " + df.Value.Replace("|", ", "));
listingTemplate = listingTemplate.Replace("[%" + df.FieldName + ".Text]", df.FieldText);
if (df.FieldType == FieldTypes.CheckboxSingle && df.Value.Length > 0)
    listingTemplate = listingTemplate.Replace("[%" + df.FieldName + ".Value]", df.FieldText);
else if (df.FieldType != FieldTypes.CheckboxSingle)
    listingTemplate = listingTemplate.Replace("[%" + df.FieldName + ".Value]", df.Value.Replace("|", ", ").Nl2Br());
listingTemplate = listingTemplate.Replace("[%" + df.FieldName + ".Value_YesNo]", (df.Value.Length > 0 ? "Yes" : "No"));
```

This works as expected but if, say, `FacebookURL` doesn't have a value it still shows up:

```
<div class="dimage"><img src="/uploads/[%Logo.Value]" /></div>
<h5>[%Name]</h5>
<div class="item">[%Address.Value]</div>
<div class="item">[%Telephone]</div>
<div class="items"><span class="item d-btn"><a href="mailto:[%Email.Value]">E-Mail</a></span> <span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%URL.Value]">Website</a></span> <span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%Video.Value]">Watch Video</a></span> <span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%BrochureURL.Value]">Brochure</a></span> <span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%ReprintURL]">Reprint</a></span> <span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%FacebookURL.Value]">Facebook</a></span> <span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%TwitterURL.Value]">Twitter</a></span></div>
<div class="item">[%Waterway]</div>
<div class="notes">[%DateAdded]</div>
```

This is where I'm running into problems:

```
<div class="head">
<div class="dimage">[?<img src="/uploads/[%Logo.Value]" />?]</div>
<h5>[%Name]</h5>
</div>
[? <div class="item">[%Address.Value]</div> ?]
[? <div class="item">[%Telephone]</div> ?]
<div class="items">[?<span class="item d-btn"><a href="mailto:[%Email.Value]">E-Mail</a></span>?] [?<span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%URL.Value]">Website</a></span>?] [?<span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%Video.Value]">Watch Video</a></span>?] [?<span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%BrochureURL.Value]">Brochure</a></span>?] [?<span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%ReprintURL.Value]">Reprint</a></span>?] [?<span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%FacebookURL.Value]">Facebook</a></span>?] [?<span class="item d-btn"><a href="[%TwitterURL.Value]">Twitter</a></span>?]</div>
<div class="notes">[%DateAdded]</div>
```

If `FacebookURL` is an empty value, I want the surrounding `[? ?]` to allow me to completely remove that field.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you're using regex for this?  Also, don't put your Google search in the title of your question; put a summary of your actual question there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I could think of an easier way I would use it. If you know of a better solution I'm all ears.

Comment: @ahwm Can you give us a before and after example of a mixture of working and non working tags and what you expect will happen?

Comment: I edited to include a little more.

Answer (score -1):

Use .Net's [match evaluator delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which can allow you to customize what actually gets replaced via C# code within the regex replace. Here is an example:

```
string data = @"[? <a href=""[%FieldName.Value]"">[%FieldName.Text]</a> ?]";

var pattern = @"\[%FieldName\.(?<Keyword>[^\]]+)\]";

Console.WriteLine (Regex.Replace(data, pattern, (mtch) =>
{

    switch (mtch.Groups["Keyword"].Value)
    {
        case "Value"       : return "http://omegacoder.com"; break;
        case "Text"        : return "OmegaMan's Musings";    break;
        case "Value_YesNo" : return "Yes No";                break;
    }

    return string.Empty
     ;
}));

/* result of WriteLine
[? <a href="http://omegacoder.com">OmegaMan's Musings</a> ?]
*/
```

Comment: I already have the code in place for this. What I'm trying to figure out is how to remove the "conditional" opening and closing in addition to everything inside of it without affecting any other conditional fields.